# Codeigniter routing base troubleshoot

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I'm having this problem: I downloaded a login/register system from the web and adapted it to my needs, setting up all the directories and rooting rules... Everything works fine, except one thing. I'm running lamp on kitematik, and my website is located in a foleder called appv2. When I go to http://localhost:8080/appv2 a white page is displayed. But if I go to http://localhost:8080/appv2/home it redirects me to my homepage... Now, how can I access directly to my homepage? 
I tried "playing" with the .htaccess and routes.php files, but I can't figure it out... It's the first time I'm having this issue. I leave you a link so you can download the entire folder with the project:
https://file.io/qtCebE
In the following I include my routing rules and .htaccess file config.

```
/////////////////////////routes.php///////////////
$route['register'] = 'user/register';
$route['login'] = 'user/login';
$route['logout'] = 'user/logout';
$route['home'] = 'user/home';
$route['appv2'] = 'user/home';

$route['default_controller'] = 'User';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['(:any)'] = 'user/$1';

//////////////////////////.htaccess////////////////
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /appv2/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /appv2/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: try $route['(:any)'] = 'user/home';

Comment: @Vickel Already tried that... not working... I also just tried again just to be sure...
I thinks the problem might be in the .htaccess file but do not get it..

Comment: check if you have $config['index_page'] = ''; in your config.php

Comment: I kinda figured it out... but not really... there's something in the codeigniter setting that is not right... In my main controller "user" the index class was empty... In that i loaded header, home and footer and when I go to http://localhost:8080/appv2 it works just fine... But it's like a "workaround" since in another project my index class of my main controller is empty and I get redirected to my homepage...

Comment: @Vickel I got this: $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is exactly what you have set it up to do.

**localhost:8080/appv2** will go to your default controller as you have defined it-  user - and will use your **user/index** method so it expects to have something in the index method. It's not a "workaround", it's how it works. It is exactly what you saw happening.

You have assumed that your route **$route['appv2'] = 'user/home';**  will kick in. Well that will only work if your link is **localhost:8080/appv2/appv2**.

Your use of **$route['(:any)'] = 'user/$1';** is questionable. It will resolve to non existing methods in your **user controller**. So I do not see the point of it in this case.

This is a quick answer so if you are unsure of anything, ask, and I'll see if I can expand on it.

Comment: I get what you are saying, and it really helped me out understanding the way codeigniter routes. But anyway I can't figure it out one thing. I can set my default controller (user in this case), and my default method is automatically index, am I right?
I'm currently taking a class on web develop. and we were told to use codeigniter. We got a brief introduction (the online tutorial for the "news"), and in that the index method is actually empty and yet it loads the homepage if you just type http://localhost:8080/example_root. Now I'm stuck on this, it's like you can change your default method.

Comment: Yes, if you just call the controller with no method the index method is always (not sometimes) called. What you are thinking is happening, isn't. You cannot have an empty index method do something. It's empty. The news example on the codeigniter site does indeed have a whole bunch of stuff in its index method so I am not sure what you are referring to.